# How to import RequireJS (AMD) module in Angular 4.x (Angular Cli) App?

Tags: angular, requirejs, angular-cli

I have a legacy JS file, written in the following RequireJS (AMD) module notation:

```
define('mymodule', [], function(){

    // ... bla bla bla

    return {
        calculate: function() { return 1 + 1; }
    };
});
```

I'm importing this file from another (legacy) project that uses RequireJS, therefore - **I can't change the module definition used**.

I want to import it in an Angular Cli (Angular 4.x) app written in TypeScript.

Since Angular Cli uses Webpack 2 to build projects, which supports AMD, I thought I can import it like this:

```
import * as MyModule from './mymodule.js';
```

... but that's not working, it triggers an error that the `mymodule.js` is not a module.

Any ideas (or workarounds) how can I import this legacy module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am able to load amd module.

here is TS:

```
import * as MyModule from './mymodule.js';

console.log('my value is', MyModule.value);
```

mymodule.js file:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports){
   exports.value = "aaa";
});
```

and in tsconfig.js

```
"allowJs": true
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use System.import provided by webpack.

```
 declare var System: any; 

 System.import('./mymodule.js')
     .then(MyModule=>console.log(MyModule.value));
```

Comment: It indeed works when the `mymodule.js` file has this `exports` injected and when the public module methods (values) are defined this way: `exports.value = "aaa";` However, my use-case is different. My `mymodule.js` file has different logic. The `define` statement lacks injection of the `exports` and it simply returns the public module methods (or values). Do you have any suggestions if I can import it **without** changing logic/structure in my `mymodule.js` (sadly, that's a primary requirements I need to deal with)?

Comment: This is named modules and i have no idea why they do not work. Try to do System.import('./mymodule.js').then(x=>console.log(x));

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. TypeScript error: `Cannot find name 'System'`

Comment: add "declare var System: any;"

Comment: Lol, great! That solved it!! Please update your answer, so I can accept it and reward you with the bounty :-) Thank you!

Comment: Is there any guide anywhere to use Angular 5 with requireJS? I'm trying to insert an Angular5 app into an AngularJS ngView (route of route)