# angular4 how to call a function in a external js

Tags: javascript, angular, function, external

I have a jscript which displays a log to the console:

x.js contains

```
function open() {
    console.log('this a function');
}
```

in index.html of my app

```
<script src="x.js"></script>
```

in my component

```
declare var xJS : any;;

@Component({
   selector: 'employerfile',
   templateUrl: './employerfile.component.html'
})

export class EmployerFileComponent
    .....
    openURL() {
       xJS.open();  
    }
}
```

in html

```
<a (click)="openURL()"> click </a>
```

When I execute this code, I get an exception@

> Original exception: xJS is not defined

How can I call this external function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Importing your file like this `<script src="x.js"></script>` will not work.

You have to import it in the following way:

```
import * as xJS from './x.js';
```

If it will not work, the alternative way is to use `System.import`:

```
declare var System: any; 

System.import('./x.js')
    .then(xJS => {
        xJS.open();
    });
```

You can check the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182566/2765346).

Comment: i have this error error_handler.js:50 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: xJS.open is not a function

Comment: Can you make your external file as a module and to export your function: `export default function open(){ .... }`

Comment: I have the same issue, but the difference is the js I am including, is in the website and not local `https://chggtt.gt/Critgtek/cfr.cerfritek.js` so any solution for this ?

Comment: @GhizlaneLotfi I have never faced with an issue with an external link. Maybe this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/34607252/2765346 Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare the name of the function you want to use in your angular component, as-

```
declare var open: any;
```

This basically tells the compiler that `open` exists somewhere, which will be then found in your `js` file.

Also, to use the above method in your component, you will have to use this syntax-

```
anyCustomMethodName/anyLifeCycleMethod() {
    new open();
}
```

Comment: what if you want to store the return value from the open() function?

Comment: When I tried your answer, I got "Modifiers can'tappear here" error.

Comment: What worked for me is I put let open: any; and then ignore the lintrule to put const , instead of let. Keep it as let. Without the 'declare' word.

Answer (score 1):

You should first import it like this:

```
import * as xJS from 'xJS';
```

Comment: I have this compile error

ERROR in C:/....app.component.ts (15,28): File 'C:/....js/x.js' is not a module.

Answer (score 1):

If your x.js file is not on your local machine or hosted on CDN or it is third-party library then you can't import it in above ways. ***Even System.import is deprecated***.

You can add your js file into index.html and call its functions using ***window*** global object as we do earlier.