# Angular 4 - Custom window object

Tags: angular

We use Angular 4 in one of our projects, and we are using a using a internal js library for encrypting the password. We include the encryption js file in our index.html, and all the functions are on window object. So when I am trying to invoke the encrypt function , encryptBCCBase64 ,from my component like
 window.encryptBCCBase64(password)
I am getting an error like -

Property 'encryptBCCBase64' does not exist on type 'Window'.

So how do I call this method from my component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular4 how to call a function in a external js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623348/angular4-how-to-call-a-function-in-a-external-js)

Comment: @maio290 thanks of the answer, but this would mean that I will have to make a copy of the file into my project folder, and not have a latest version of the file, so how do I this dynamically ? Say when I the refer the  the script from my html, I'd be giving it as <script type="text/javascript" href="/bcc/encryptionbcc.js'>

Comment: Try adding `declare let window: any;` at the top of the file where you use your method

Answer (score 0):

You are using a custom Window, that extends the original Window object.
You should declare an interface with the added properties, something like

```
export interface CustomWindow extends Window {
  encryptBCCBase64: (string) => void;
}
export class YourClass {
  private window: CustomWindow;
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    this.window = this.document.defaultView as any;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // usage example
    console.log(this.window.encryptBCCBase64);
  }
}
```

Similar to what is explained in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/how-to-inject-window-into-a-service/52620181#52620181).

Not sure if it works for angular 4.

Comment: Question needs additional information.